# EF Core 5 - Preferred way or best practice to connect to read only db for queries

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there any preferred way to when using CQS/CQRS, to have a subsequent connection to a read-only database?   I can make it work with a second dbcontext, adding NoTracking to queries and raising an exception on SaveChanges etc, but I would have thought there was some built in support or standard convention as this would be a common enterprise requirement.

Comment: Do you already have a read-only database or do you want to connect to a database only via read-only settings/configurations?

Comment: The question is moot. A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. A DbContext works disconnected. It doesn't use a *single* connection. It creates a new connection each time it has to load data or save *all* cached changes with a single `SaveChanges` and closes it immediately. If you use a DbContext properly, ie create a new one and keep it around only long enough to serve a single UoW/scenario/use case/process,  you won't have to do much more. You don't have to throw exceptions in any ycase

Comment: The *only* thing extra thing you may need to do is use `NoTracking` when you don't won't to track entities. This has little to do with read-only access though. You don't need a read-only DbContext to implement CQRS.

Comment: I already have the read-only database.  One Master for the writes and one read-only replica for reads.

Comment: I understand the DbContext is not a connection, but I dont think I have have multiple connections to different databases on the same context?